# Arduino AD-converter tolerance

Tags: c++, analogread, hardware, analog-sampling

I created a quite simple Arduino sketch:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
  Serial.println(sensorValue);  

  float voltage = sensorValue * (5 / 1023.0); 
  Serial.println(voltage);

  delay(1000);
}
```

I use the following circuit:

[image]

My multimeter measures **3.31 V**, between the pin 3V3 and GND.

I get a *sensorValue* of **730** and a calculated *voltage* of **3.57 V**. This is 8% higher that 3.3V. What is the tolerance by the AD-converter?

Comment: Did you connect the 3V3 directly to A0 with no current limiting resistor?

Comment: Of course. I added a picture of my circuit.

Comment: Is the circuit's supply a USB? if so, the 5V can have a 5% error... Moreover are you measuring between 3V3 and A0 or A0 and ground?

Comment: I measure between 3V3 and ground. I will fix it in my question.

Comment: It is powered via USB and I have 3.31V. So, this 5% tolerance is not the problem. My problem must be something with the ADC.

Comment: What voltage does your voltmeter say the "5V" supply is? That's the 5.000 that you're using in your calculation.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhh. It is just 4,65 V. This is 7%. Fixing my formula to  `voltage = sensorValue * (4.65 / 1023.0)` returns 3.3V.

Comment: In engineering (and usually also in life in general) when asking questions or seeking to learn, it is usually wise to avoid the mind set that goes with "Of course" and " ...the problem MUST BE something with ...". Both of these lock you into mindsets that hide information and/or  decrease the likelihood that people will make the effort to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The absolute accuracy of the ADC in the ATmega328P when its clock is within its optimal range is given [in the datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf) as 2LSB. This means that the actual value could be anywhere between 728 and 732.

Of course this depends on the accuracy of V<sub>CC</sub>, since it is being used as the ADC reference. This is why supply voltage measurements should be performed [using the internal bandgap voltage](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1794/arduino-adc-reference-voltage-if-it-is-battery-powered) instead.

Comment: Okay. Can you expain it a bit more detailed? Were are the 728 and 732 coming from? Like this, my 730 are fitting well. But then, calcuating the voltage does not fit: `sensorValue * (5 / 1023.0) = 730*5/1023 = 3.57`.

Comment: Did you read the first sentence of the answer?

Comment: 730+-2LSB is 728/732. That is clear. Let me change my question: why is the value 730 for 3.3V and not 675+-2LSB?

Comment: The value 675 in the formula `sensorValue * (5 / 1023.0)` would give me a voltage of 3.3.

Comment: If I change the formula to `sensorValue * (3.3 / 730.0)`, it returns the correct values for other input voltages. I still dont know, why it is the value `730`

Comment: Please measure the value of your 5 volts, and tell us what it is. At a guess it's about 4.7 volts. Also, make sure to measure the voltage right on the Arduino board.

Comment: @Dennis: If 730 count is 3.31V, 1023 count is about 4.64V. Your supply voltage is low. Which is what the second paragraph covers.

Comment: Right, my input voltage is to low. With some adjustments, everything fits now.